# Can this type of workflow possible in Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, hadoop2, oozie-coordinator

Can this type of workflow possible in Oozie?

or any suggestions on how to do this type of things in oozie

Please look at the picture attached

http://s7.postimg.org/yj30wb0mj/oozie_Workflow.jpg

Task3 should be run by only one work flow at a time other workflow needs to wait.

Task3 is ssh action only one needs to access that machine at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.

Using the [fork and join](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.5_Fork_and_Join_Control_Nodes)

Fork to create wf 1 & 2 and join then start task 3 , than fork again .

You may need to refactor your action to match this design and split your workflows, so the design will match what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the answer, any workflow that can be represented in the form of a [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) is possible in Oozie. Ofcourse, this is bounded by the ecosytem and tools supported by Oozie.